# uncaught error: cannot read property length of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keeep on getting this error anytime I run my app.. it loads the scss file but the js script throws this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at IndecisionApp.render (IndecisionApp.js?8eb7:80)....
```

here is my IndecisionApp component

```
import React from 'react';
import AddOption from './AddOption';
import Action from './Action';
import Header from './Header';
import Options from './Options';
import OptionModal from './OptionModal';

export default class IndecisionApp extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleDeleteOptions = this.handleDeleteOptions.bind(this);
    this.handlePick = this.handlePick.bind(this)
    this.handleAddOption = this.handleAddOption.bind(this)
    this.handleDeleteOption = this.handleDeleteOption.bind(this);
    this.handleClearSelectedOption = this.handleClearSelectedOption.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        option: [],
        selectedOption: undefined
    }
}

handleDeleteOptions (){
    this.setState(() => ({ options: [] }));
};
handleClearSelectedOption () {
    this.setState(() => ({ selectedOption: undefined }));
}
handleDeleteOption (optionToRemove){
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        options: prevState.options.filter((option) => optionToRemove !== option)
    }));
};
handlePick () {
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.options.length);
    const option = this.state.options[randomNum];
    this.setState(() => ({
        selectedOption: option
    }));
};
handleAddOption (option){
    if (!option) {
        return 'Enter valid value to add item';
    } else if (this.state.options.indexOf(option) > -1) {
        return 'This option already exists';
    }

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        options: prevState.options.concat(option)
    }));
};
componentDidMount() {
    try {
        const json = localStorage.getItem('options');
        const options = JSON.parse(json);

        if (options) {
            this.setState(() => ({ options }));
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // Do nothing at all
    }
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.options.length !== this.state.options.length) {
        const json = JSON.stringify(this.state.options);
        localStorage.setItem('options', json);
    }
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('componentWillUnmount');
}
render() {
    const subtitle = 'Put your life in the hands of a computer';

    return (
        <div>
            <Header subtitle={subtitle} />
            <div className="container">
                <Action
                    hasOptions={this.state.options.length > 0}
                    handlePick={this.handlePick}
                />
                <div className="widget">
                    <Options
                        options={this.state.options}
                        handleDeleteOptions={this.handleDeleteOptions}
                        handleDeleteOption={this.handleDeleteOption}
                    />
                    <AddOption
                        handleAddOption={this.handleAddOption}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <OptionModal
                selectedOption={this.state.selectedOption}
                handleClearSelectedOption={this.handleClearSelectedOption}
            />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me out. I have spent days trying to solve this issue to no avail. I tried all I could trying to fix this bug in the code.

Comment: Typo - `this.state.option` -> `this.state.optionS`

Comment: Please provide only relevant code to the issue. It  becomes very much difficult to find out what's going on there while looking in the code.

Comment: well noted.. appreciate your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set your initial state in the constructor, you assign it to `option` not `options` with an `s`.

`componentDidMount` is called AFTER all of the children's `componentDidMount` and `render` methods are called. So, you're trying to look for the state object of `options` when you initialized with `option` so there is no length to look up.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you set the name of the state as option without s but when you call it you are using this.state.options with s, i think that this is your problem

Comment: Typo should not be answer. It's  just an off topic in SO as this doesn't help for future visitors.

Comment: i  change state.option to state.options in the constructor and it worked... cant believe i miss this

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get those errors it usually means there's a misspelling or an error in the way I pass in props or state. For you it looks like you define the property `'option'` in your initial state in the constructor, but in your render method you're calling `this.state.options`

Answer (score -1):

In your constructor you set the name of the state as option without s but when you call it you are using this.state.options with s, i think that this is your problem

option: []

this.state.options